# how to write query with joins

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

How I can make this query into single query? Can we use joins?

```
SELECT 
    id, parentID, name 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        GroupActivities.groupID AS "groupID",  
        max(GroupActivities.id) AS "activityID" 
    FROM GroupActivities 
    GROUP BY groupID
    ) AS anon_4, Groups
WHERE 
    Groups.id = anon_4.groupID
ORDER BY 
    anon_4.activityID DESC
```

We have two tables: 
 1) Groups: columns as id,parentID,name 
 2) GroupActivities: columns as id,groupID

Comment: This is a single query already

Comment: in order to get help, you need to provide more information: a diagram with the tables involved and their relationships would be useful.

Comment: I formatted the code to be more readable. I got stuck on `AS anon Groups`, what seemed to me a missing comma and the use of `anon_4`, a name that wasn't introduced. Maybe mistakes by reducing the original statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to obtain out of that query, but I'll try to offer you an answer. Using a JOIN in that situation can be done, but I cannot see how it would bring you any benefit (technically, I think you are already using a form of join there).

If I understood your query correctly, you are trying to get some basic information about each group while sorting them in a descending order, having the maximum GroupActivities.id associated with that group id as sort criteria. Am I right?
Well, since you need the maximum from another table I see no way to avoid a select subquery.
That being said, this is the solution I propose (hard to say if it is any better than yours, maybe some SQL guru around here can tell us which one performs better):

```
SELECT g.id, g.parentID, g.name
FROM Groups AS g
ORDER BY 
(
    SELECT MAX(ga.id) 
    FROM GroupActivities AS ga 
    WHERE ga.groupId = g.id
)
DESC;
```